# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException clicking continue button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been playing around with selenium in java and I have come across an issue that I cant figure out.

on this page here:  http://www.legalcontracts.com/contracts/lease-agreement-form/?ldcn=menu+name

going from the third page (address page) to the fourth 
I am able to set the address:

```
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class=' qd spropertyAddress']/div[@class='ans']/input")
    private WebElement address;

public void SetAddress(String addressName){
        address.sendKeys(addressName);
    }
```

but when I try to continue

```
@FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(text(),'Continue')]")
    private WebElement continuebutton;
continuebutton.click();
```

I get an `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException`. The continue button is the same id `@FindBy` as the previous page so I'm not sure if that has something to do with it.  I have tried a many different ways to try to handle this but the only way that seems to work is to `thread.sleep` which is not a great way of handling this.

things I have tried:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(continuebutton));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(continuebutton));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated((By) continuebutton));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By) continuebutton));


public void waitForJQuery(WebDriver driver) {
    (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) d;
            return (Boolean) js.executeScript("return !!window.jQuery && window.jQuery.active == 0");
        }
    });
}

public void waitForJavaScript(WebDriver driver){
    (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    }
);

public void checkPageIsReady(WebDriver driver) { JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; //Initially bellow given if condition will check ready state of page. 

    if (js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete")){ 
        System.out.println("Page Is loaded."); 
        return; 
        } 

    //This loop will rotate for 25 times to check If page Is ready after every 1 second. 
    //You can replace your value with 25 If you wants to Increase or decrease wait time. 
    for (int i=0; i<25; i++){ 
        try { 
            Thread.sleep(1000); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {} 

        //To check page ready state. 
        if (js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete")){ 
            break; } } 
    }
```

I come in from the previous page with the same continue but in a different page object:

```
@FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(text(),'Continue')]")
    private WebElement continuebutton;
continuebutton.click();
```

Could selenium be confusing the current continue button with the previous one?

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.ans>input#ctl00_Content_ctrlQuestions_ctl194_ctl21_ctl06_ctl01_ctl01_ctl01_in")).click();

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.ans>input#ctl00_Content_ctrlQuestions_ctl194_ctl21_ctl06_ctl01_ctl01_ctl01_in")).clear();

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.ans>input#ctl00_Content_ctrlQuestions_ctl194_ctl21_ctl06_ctl01_ctl01_ctl01_in")).sendKeys("ur address");

Thread.sleep(2000);

//click on continue button

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("  .largeProceedButton.continueButtonnContinueFirst.nContinue")).click();
```

use the cssSelector instead of xpath what i mention above to click on continue button.

Comment: I am trying to not use any thread.sleeps in my code.  If I use a sleep everything works ok, but its not a guarantee that the click will work

Comment: I just use this for testing purpose.....no need to use this wait.....u can click on continue button without this wait....u told that u cant click on continue button...just use my css path for that click

Comment: U can use explicit wait if u want like this:  (new WebdriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable("by ur locator"));

Comment: Nope still doesn't work with using the css.  The issue I am having is that I am not able to click the button when I click continue from the previous page, enter text then click the continue button again on the address page.  I can click the button fine if I use a thread.sleep(2000).  I also tried using the ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable but this doesn't seem to be waiting for the element.